# Undefined Value When Converting Metrics

Tags: javascript

One of my recent projects is to successfully get the temperature to convert from Fahrenheit to Celsius. However, I have run into a problem that gives me an undefined value when I click my button. Should I be referring to the temperature value that I have requested from my API? I believe that my conversion within my weather function isn't running when I call it.
Here's my codepen.

https://codepen.io/baquino1994/pen/qXjXOM?editors=0010

HTML

```
<span id="temp"></span>
<button id="tempunit">F</button>
```

JS

```
function weather(){
    function success(position){
        var latitude = position.coords.latitude;
    var longitude= position.coords.longitude;
        // location.innerHTML = "Latitude:" + latitude+"°"+ "Longitude: " + longitude+'°';
        var theUrl = url +apiKey + "/"+ latitude+","+ longitude +"?callback=?";

    $.getJSON(theUrl, function(data){
        $("#temp").html(data.currently.temperature)
      $("#minutely").html(data.minutely.summary)
      // currentTempInFahrenheit = Math.round(data.html.currently.temperature * 10) /
      $("#tempunit").text(tempUnit);

  $.ajax({
      url:'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=40.714224,-73.961452&key=AIzaSyBpiTf5uzEtJsKXReoOKXYw4RO0ayT2Opc', dataType: 'json',
     success: function(results){
         $("#city").text(results.results[3].address_components[4].long_name)
  $("#country").text(results.results[0].address_components[5].long_name)

     }


 }

  )}
             );
   }    


var location = document.getElementById("location");
var apiKey = "3827754c14ed9dd9c84afdc4fc05a1b3";
var url = "https://api.darksky.net/forecast/";
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success);
// location.innerHTML = "Locating...";

   }
$(document).ready(function(){ 
weather();
 });
var tempUnit = "F";
var currentTempInFahrenheit;



$("#tempunit").click(function(){
    var currentTempUnit = $("#tempunit").text();
    var newTempUnit  = currentTempUnit  == "F" ? "C" : "F";
    $('#tempunit').text(newTempUnit);
    if(newTempUnit == "F"){
    var celTemp = Math.round(parseInt($('#temp').text())*5/9 - 32);
        $("#temp").text(celTemp + " " + String.fromCharcode(176));
    }
    else{
        $("#temp").text(currentTempInFahrenheit + " " + String.fromCharCode(176));
    }



})
```

Answer (score 0):

try this, my browser blocked geolocation, when i mocked the location i was able to get the codepen to work.

```
var location = document.getElementById("location");
var apiKey = "3827754c14ed9dd9c84afdc4fc05a1b3";
var url = "https://api.darksky.net/forecast/";
// navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success);
var position = { coords: { latitude: 32, longitude: -96 } };
success(position);
```